# MYSQL Insert todays date to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I' am running a query on table **tblpages_copy** to get the row datecreated and updating **tblpages_copy2** in the same loop. For some reason in datecreated in the **tblpages_copy2** it enters todays date.

I have checked the $date2 values and its prefectly fine its a correct value. The type of the datecreated in **tblpages_copy** is string

HERE IS THE QUERY

```
$i=0;
$q = mysql_query( "SELECT datecreated FROM tblpages_copy" );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $datecreated = $row["datecreated"];
    $date = strtotime($datecreated);
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

    $q2 = mysql_query( 'UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = ' . $date2 . ' ');
        if($q2){
            echo $i++ .'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.  $q2  . '&nbsp;' . $date2 . "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo mysql_error() . "<br/>";   
        }
}
```

MySQL error dump is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'xx' at line 1
```

What I suspect is that the Update query was wrong. I have tried few ways yet no luck

```
$q2 = mysql_query( "UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = '$date2'");
$q2 = mysql_query( "UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = ". $date2);
```

Comment: first check the `$date2` value ...

Comment: **$date2** does return correct value...

Comment: To start debugging, you should echo your resultant SQL statement.

Comment: I' am doing that 
 `echo $i++ .'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.  $q2  . '&nbsp;' . $date2 . "<br/>";`

Comment: In database side what is the type of datecreated field.

Comment: Change this `('UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = ' . $date2 . ' ')` to `( "UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = '" . $date2 . "' ")` which is an option.

Comment: @Fred -ii-, I did tried that but still its insert todays date into tblpages_copy2 thanks!

Comment: You probably need a `WHERE` clause. @NavneilNaicker for example `WHERE datecreated=?` or something to that affect. See this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm and if you want to enter today's date, you can use the built-in `NOW()` function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Fred -ii- thanks you are awesome. That did the work...

Comment: You're welcome. Am curious though, were you talking about the `WHERE` clause or the `NOW()` function, from my comment? @NavneilNaicker

Comment: @Fred -ii- it was WHERE CLAUSE that was missing. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
mysql_query( 'UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = ' . $date2 . ' ');
```

to

```
mysql_query( 'UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = "' . $date2 . '"');
```

and I bet it works. Dates are strings like anything else and must be quoted.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this, surrounding `$date2` with `'` and also using `"`'s for the query instead of `'`'s:

```
$q2 = mysql_query("UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = "' . $date2 . '" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'UPDATE tblpages_copy2 SET datecreated = "' . $date2 . '"'
```

Don`t use mysql_* functions. mysql_* functions are deprecated. You can use PDO and Mysqli

Comment: thanks for the advise, I have converted to mysqli and also try you sql but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @NavneilNaicker   what is value of $datecreated ?